# Make controller view to act as a game controller Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi, gamecontroller

I am following below links to making controller view

1. https://github.com/andretietz/controller-lib
2. http://www.akexorcist.com/2012/10/android-code-joystick-controller.html

Now view part has been done and I am able to detect button press and all things, now the question is how I can send controls to games running on device? Obviously, It connects through bluetooth/Wi-Fi but I am not getting any proper resource to do these things. My controller would work for any third party games which support bluetooth based controller.

**Q. What devices are involved?**

**Ans:** 2 Android devices connected through bluetooth.

**Q. How should or can they communicate?**

**Ans:** Using bluetooth connectivity.

**Q. What kind of commands do the controller send, what kind of commands/api the games are listening too?**

**Ans:** Controller is based on touch input event given by user on 1st devices, any third party games which can be able to listen user input event coming from second device which is connected through bluetooth.

Comment: You want to run the controller and the game on the same device?

Comment: No, diff devices connected through bluetooth.